# Contribute, Word usage

Tags: word-usage

I'm preparing my CV. I was wondering if I have used the word contribute i n a correct way :
My Main roles were **contributing** in Drainage design, Storm water design and developing Systems.

Answer (score 1):

The preposition that follows the verb "contribute" is "to", not "in".

That said, using a present participle after copulative "be" may sound like the present progressive of the verb "contribute", which is clearly not the intended meaning. Even using an infinitive might be mistaken for the construction denoting future or obligation "be to infinitive". Therefore, I suggest changing "were" to "included" or "consisted of".

Another inconsistency I find is that the sentence proposed contains two nouns ("design", which is unnecessarily repeated twice) and a gerund ("developing"), and that causes some unbalance.

Based on the definitions above and on the assumption that "systems" is related to the nouns "drainage" and "storm water" (otherwise, some further change would be required), this is what I suggest:

- My main roles consisted of contributing to / taking part in the design and development of drainage and storm water systems.